# Raspberry reading Arduino via serial from Python freezes

Tags: python-2.7, arduino, raspberry-pi

I have built a weight scale connected to an Arduino, which is publishing the measured weight into USB serial. When connecting via the Arduino IDE from my laptop, the serial monitor nicely shows the data arriving.
When using the below Python code to read the serial, it works on the laptop (Linux Mint, Python 2.7.6), but from the Raspberry (RPI B+ running Raspbian, Python 2.7.3) it freezes after a few lines printed (number of lines printed before freezing changes between 7-70)

```
import serial, time
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB1', 9600, timeout=5)
time.sleep(2) # wait for Arduino
num = 0;

while True:
    line = ser.readline()
    num = num+1
    print num
    print line
```

Any idea what might be causing this freezing on the Raspberry?

Comment: Is the Arduino always sending a `newline` character?

Comment: Yes, it sends the below in every 200 ms 
Serial.println("");
   Serial.print("analogValue:|");Serial.print(analogValueAverage);Serial.print("|");Serial.print(" load: |");Serial.print(load,5);Serial.print("|");

Comment: Try putting the `Serial.println("");` at the end instead of the beginning.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that (move the Serial.println("") to the end instead of the beginning). It seems it has helped somewhat as now sometimes it gets to 140 messages before it dies, but other times it still dies at 20-30 messages.

Comment: `ser.readline()` is waiting for a `newline` character in your python code, so if moving `Serial.println("")`  to the end in your arduino code helped some then it looks like a timeout issue on the python side. You could try increasing your timeout or somehow reading a little more dynamically.

Comment: I have doubled the timeout from 5 to 10, but no change. I also tried the opposite (decreased from 5 to 1) to see whether it will make it worse, but no change that way either.